# How to resolve a conflict in dependency version in a nuget package?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, nuget, unity-container

We're developing a class library that's being packaged as nuget. That library has a dependency on Unity.Container. We're distributing this library to be used by a couple of other projects of other teams. Those projects both uses Unity.Container. But the problem is that one of the projects uses an older version of Unity and updating/changing version is not an option for both projects.

1. How can I package my nuget library in a way that we can satisfy the version of both projects?

The only thing we're using in Unity.Container are just the basics, RegisterType, RegisterInstance and Resolve.

2. Is there a design pattern that will totally eliminate the need to add Unity.Container as a dependency in our nuget package?

Comment: Is their any interchange of types from `Unity.Container` between your class library and its dependents?

Comment: No, we're just using the UnityContainer's methods for register and resolve.

Comment: Then a binding redirect should work as suggested by Alexander Powolozki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use assembly redirect in the target project to point to the desired version of references assembly (unity.container).

Comment: Surely you can do better than this, probably useful to add the syntax for the redirect, how you would find the token and the right version number ect

Comment: @MichaelRandall having the keyword "Assembly binding redirect" one can google all relevant informations within 15 seconds.